# Create an app to lauch from lockscreen without unlocking

Tags: android, lockscreen

I can put 2 shortcuts on the lockscreen, and with every application installed on my android device. However, I need to unlock the screen when I slide one of those shortcuts, except for the camera: I don't need to unlock and when I close the camera the device shows the lockscreen again.

Now I want to create an application that the user can put in shortcut and opens without unlocking, like for the camera. How can I create that?

I don't want to root my smartphone or install other applications to change the lockscreen.

Thanks you!

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english and my troubles to explain my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot unlock the device however you can show an activity over lock screen.

Call this when your activity is launched:

`activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);`